# schadule task in DSS 3.5 for DSS project box car

Tags: wso2, scheduled-tasks, wso2-data-services-server

I created a Data service project and enabled Boxcar for running 5 queries sequentially.
after deploying service, I need to use schedule task for running it every 5 minutes. in schedule  task, I selected _request_box operation(It was created by DSS boxcar) but it doesn't work. how can i use task schedule with boxcarring?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a task is scheduled the operation should be a parameter-less operation. As request_box consists of several other operations, this scenario will not work as a normal operation. I have added a [JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DS-1207) to report this scenario and you can track the progress from there.